Android Studio Convention type has been deprecated
Hello I am trying to learn app development and trying to implement Google firebase, but getting error that "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0."
Tried to build with - org.gradle.warning.mode=all and it said that "The org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.logConventionDeprecation(DefaultConvention.java:392)
at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultConvention.getPlugins(DefaultConvention.java:67)
"
Tried searching where Convention is used but could't find any location.
Maybe someone could suggest whats the problem here?
this is my build gradle
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")

    
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.naujasprojektas"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.naujasprojektas"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:25.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:25.1.0")
    implementation(libs.firebase.firestore)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}

And libs.version.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.6.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.10.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.10.0"
activity = "1.8.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.7.7"
navigationUiKtx = "2.7.7"
googleGmsGoogleServices = "4.4.2"
firebaseDatabase = "21.0.0"
firebaseFirestore = "25.1.0"
firebaseAuth = "23.0.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationUiKtx" }
firebase-database = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-database", version.ref = "firebaseDatabase" }
firebase-firestore = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-firestore", version.ref = "firebaseFirestore" }
firebase-auth = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth", version.ref = "firebaseAuth" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
google-gms-google-services = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "googleGmsGoogleServices" }



